# Using Listener for SeekBar's changing progress cusing pause/play in playing with MediaPlayer

Tags: android

When I use this code to controling MediaPlayer by SeekBar MediaPlayer doesn't play continuesly.

1:Plays

0:Pause

Plays Like this !

11110001110011

What's problem?

Code:

```
sb_song.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mp_qiraat.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mp_qiraat.pause();
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mp_qiraat.seekTo(arg1);
            }
        });

        tb_play_qiraat.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
                vib.vibrate(80);
                mp_qiraat.reset();
                mp_qiraat.stop();
                rl_media.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onProgressChanged` called many times (frequently) during SeekBar seek process.

You **MUST** save new seek position when onProgressChanged called as some variable and call `seekTo(pos)` only when `onStopTrackingTouch()` callback is invoked which means seek process is completed and you have to call `MediaPlayer.seekTo(seekPos)` API.

Than you seek process will become more smooth and I think this problem will disappear.